# Add specific artifact to a Gradle project (Androind)

Tags: android, gradle, import, artifact

I need to use, in an Android project using Gradle, a specific artifact of a repositorty.
The artifact is  *`kotlinx-serialization-cbor` version 0.20.0* (available in the [readme](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/formats/README.md#cbor)) from [the kotlinx serialization GitHub project](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization).
I don't know where and how to add this specific dependencies. (Probably I should add something in "gradle.build" file, the one marked as *Project:YourProjectName* or the one *Module:app*
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The README in the root of the [github project](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) explains how to add the plugins to your project. So long as your gradle install is up to date you just need to add a section at the top of your app level `build.gradle` like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.3.70' // or any other kotlin plugin
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.3.70'
}
```

In the same file make sure jcenter is included in your repositories:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Then again in the same file add the basic library, as well as the cbor library to the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version" // or "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.20.0" // JVM dependency
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-cbor:0.20.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-serialization-cbor/0.20.0 and copy-paste from Gradle/Maven etc (build system of your choice).